# Net Core: Resolve "Add a way to break out of this property accessor's recursion"

Tags: c#, linq, generics, .net-core, sonarqube

I am trying to  create a simple class. ColumnSort member is a list of items in comma delimited text "Car,Book,Food".

ColumnSortList creates a List

1. Car
2. Book
3. Food

C# and SonarQube is mentioning items like Error

> Get: Add a way to break out of this property accessor's recursion.
>
> Set: Use the 'value' parameter in this property set accessor declaration

How would I resolve these to make warnings/ errors (in SonarQube) go away? Open to making code more efficient also.

Note: columnSortList is purely supposed to be a read only computed field from ColumnSort string.

```
public class PageModel
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }
    public string ColumnSort { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> columnSortList
    {
        get
        {
            return columnSortList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ColumnSort == null)
            {
                columnSortList = null;
            }
            else
            {
                columnSortList = ColumnSort.Split(',')
                             .Select(x => x.Trim())
                             .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                             .AsEnumerable();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `columnSortList` property needs a backing field.  You are getting and setting it from inside itself.

Comment: hi @BrianRogers columnSortList is purely supposed to be a read only computed field from ColumnSort string, how would I resolve this? thanks

Comment: If it's supposed to be read-only then you should not have a set method.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `columnSortList` is intended to be purely read-only, computed from `ColumnSort`, then you should not have a `set` method at all.  All the logic should go inside `get` like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> columnSortList
{
    get
    {
        if (ColumnSort == null)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
        else
        {
            return ColumnSort.Split(',')
                             .Select(x => x.Trim())
                             .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                             .AsEnumerable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: now its saying, "return an empty collection instead of null", will research this also, thanks

Comment: Change `return null;` to `return Enumerable.Empty<string>();` in that case.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: also placed a purely technical question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634401/what-is-property-accessor-recursion-in-c , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your getter is returning itself, which you can't do, and your setter is setting itself, which you also can't do.  This here seems to be what you want:

```
public IEnumerable<string> columnSortList
{
    get
    {
        if (ColumSort == null)
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
        else
        {
            return ColumnSort.Split(',')
                         .Select(x => x.Trim())
                         .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                         .AsEnumerable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: now its saying, return an empty collection instead of null, will research this also,

Comment: hi,return Enumerable.Empty<string>();, I'm doing this since its Enumerable, it fixed on my end also

Comment: also placed a purely technical question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634401/what-is-property-accessor-recursion-in-c , thanks