# What is Property Accessor Recursion in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, class, .net-core, software-design

What is Property Accessor Recursion in C#? I see articles of how to resolve it, but want a pure technical definition of what it is.

Resources on how to resolve it:

[c# property setter body without declaring a class-level property variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238649/c-sharp-property-setter-body-without-declaring-a-class-level-property-variable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It becomes clearer if you think of the getters and setters as methods (they really are methods in the background - C# just hides that from you).

- Whenever you retrieve the value of a property, you are calling the get method
- Whenever you set the value of a property, you are calling the set method

So if you have a property that looks like this:

```
public string MyProperty {
    get {
        return this.MyProperty;
    }
    set {
        this.MyProperty = value;
    }
}
```

That is really like having these two methods:

```
string get_MyProperty() {
    return get_MyProperty();
}

void set_MyProperty(string value) {
    set_MyProperty(value);
}
```

You will notice that both cases will result in infinite recursion that will end with a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

So Don't Do That™

Comment: Part of the problem (as evidenced by his previous question) is that the names look similar and are the reverse of generally accepted .NET naming conventions, so it's difficult to recognize which is a property and which is a field and, worse, when it's actually referring back to the same property instead of the backing field.

Comment: and so the correct way is just to use {get;set;} that will fix it? correct, seems like standard practice

Comment: hi @madreflection what is the correct naming convention? I can fix in code, thanks

Comment: @MattSmith That's only "correct" if you don't need to do anything else when getting or setting the value.

Comment: @MattSmith: see [General Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions).

Comment: interesting, wonder how they did in the old days, believe they used value, etc

Comment: *"believe they used value"* - Do you mean the `value` keyword in a setter? Were you referring to the "old days" of .NET, before auto-implemented properties? Yes, and they still do. That's the implicit argument to the setter, as Gabriel Luci clearly showed in the expanded versions.

Comment: Before properties existed? The reason properties exist is to control how code outside of your class can read/write values inside the class. If you just have a public field, then any other code can read/write it with anything. Without properties, you would keep the field private and write your own methods to read/write it. These are called [mutator methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method). C# properties are exactly that in the background, just easier for the programmer.

Comment: It help to read through [Microsoft's article on C# properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Comment: Java convention is to use `getProperty` / `setProperty` (without underscores). Microsoft tried to get properties, events, and other stuff into Java but when Sun resisted, Microsoft made .NET instead.

Comment: @madreflection Yeah, I knew they *were* used in Java, but I haven't touched Java since 2005 I think, so I wasn't sure if they invented properties yet. Thanks for the background info.